# what is the probability of event occurrence for a given period?

Tags: probability

Assume that event occurrence intervals subject to certain p.d.f. $f(x)$, defined in region $(a,b)$, then what is the probability that at least one event occurs in period $T$?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? At present (and despite the good will of an answerer) it is basically impossible to understand it.

Comment: Basically this question can be described as the following scenario: assume people pass by one landmark in the street, and also the arrive intervals subject to p.d.f. f(x), so what is the probability that for the interval T, we can see at least one person pass by the landmark? Obviously, if all arrive intervals (a,b) are less than the observed intervals T, at least one person must pass by the landmark in the observed intervals T

Answer (score 0):

The probability that at least one event occurs in period $T$ is one minus the probability that no event occurs in $T$, which is equal to one minus the probability that all events occur outside of $T$.

If your $n$ events are independent the probability that all events occur outside of $T$ is equal to the probability of one event occurring outside $T$ raised to the $n$th power.

For a more precise answer you will have to ask a more precise question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ignore some additional conditions:assume event occurs independently and randomly; we also do not specify the start time of $T$. So if $b<T$, should the probability be one? what  about other cases for $a>T$, $a<T<b$?

Comment: Is $T$ a single point or an interval? If it is a single point, the probability of an event occurring at $T$ is zero if the time of occurrence is distributed continuously.

Comment: $T$ is interval, a segment of time.

Comment: If the distribution of the time of occurrences is supported on $(a,b)$, and if $(a,b)$ and $T$ are disjoint, then all events occur outside $T$ with probability one; in particular, the probability that at least one event occurs outside $T$ is equal to one. I don't understand what you mean by $b<T$, $a>T$, or $a<T<b$ if $T$ is an interval.

Comment: I did not describe this problem clearly. Consider the following scenario: people pass by one landmark in the street, and also the arrive intervals subject to  p.d.f. $f(x)$, so what is the probability that for the interval $T$, we can see at least one person pass by the landmark? if all arrive intervals $(a, b)$ are less than the observed intervals $T$, at least one person must pass by the landmark in the observed intervals $T$.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your question. I may post another answer later.